# Рассылка в телеграмм боте python telebot: "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'subscribe' was never awaited task"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот, рассылка

необходимо сделать рассылку, чтобы пользователь выбирал команду подписки/отписки и ему приходили новости, пока что пробовала настроить команды и подключение бд, где будет фиксироваться состояние подписки на рассылку.
есть модуль с рассылкой, есть основной код программы, у меня не запускаются обе команды, пишет "near "user_id": syntax error", не понимаю как исправить, копировала чужой код, меняя на свои переменные+функция в основном коде программы была асинхронной, я поменяла на обычную, т.к. не работало, была ошибка:

> "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'subscribe' was never awaited task(*args,
> **kwargs) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

**код модуля:**

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен', parse_mode='HTML')
class subscribe:
def __init__(self, database):
self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database, check_same_thread=False)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
def get_subscriptions(self, status = True):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Subscription WHERE status = ?", (status,)).fetchall()
  def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Subscription WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(result)
  def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status = True):
    """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Subscription user_id, status VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,status))
  def update_subscription(self, user_id, status):
    """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE Subscription SET status = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (status, user_id))
  def close(self):
    self.connection.close()`
```

**код основного файла где прописываются функции с командами:**

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
from subscription_m import subscribe
db = subscribe('botdb.db')
conn = sqlite3.connect('botdb.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен', parse_mode='HTML')
# Команда активации подписки
@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
def subscribe(message):
if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
else:
db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
bot.send_message("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
def unsubscribe(message):
if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
bot.send_message("Вы итак не подписаны.")
else:
db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
bot.send_message("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")
```

Ошибка №2: Сообщение = send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text' Источник = C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py Трассировка стека: File "C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py", line 47, in subscribe bot.send_message("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!")

```
    2021-04-06 11:39:33,876 (util.py:75 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 241, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 102, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
"
ERROR:TeleBot:ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 285, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 255, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 241, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 102, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: `пишет "near "user_id": syntax error"` а вот тут подробнее. Добавьте по этой ошибке трассу стека

Comment: @gil9red вот полное сообщение об ошибке:
  Сообщение = near "user_id": syntax error
  Источник = C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py
  Трассировка стека:
  File "C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py", line 42, in subscribe
    db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)

Comment: Попробуйте поправить запрос в `add_subscriber` на `INSERT INTO Subscription (user_id, status) VALUES(?,?)`. Кст, а трассу стека вы не всю приложили, там явно было больше строк и комментарии плохо подходят для такого, поэтому в следующий раз прикладывайте к вопросу :)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, я просто в первый раз задаю вопрос на подобном сайте и не совсем пока разобралась как что работает
теперь выдаёт новую ошибку: 
  Сообщение = send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
  Источник = C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py
  Трассировка стека:
  File "C:\Users\Acer\source\repos\bot\bot\bot.py", line 47, in subscribe
    bot.send_message("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!")

Comment: @gil9red я отредактировала и добавила все строки трассы стека новой ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Уверен, что в `send_message` нужно минимум 2 параметра передавать и вторым будет текст сообщения ;) Потому что, текст ошибки явно говорит, что в функцию не передали значения для обязательного параметра `text`

Comment: @gil9red, да, добавила message.chat.id перед текстом и заработало, спасибо большое за помощь и извините за неопытность.

Comment: пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ и опишите в нем что поменяли в коде вопроса, чтобы проблема была исправлена :)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, сделала)

Comment: Вы молодец :) Немного отрефакторил ответ. Как получится, примите его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение:**
исправила код в функции `add_subscriber`:

```
def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status = True):
    """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Subscription (user_id, status) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id, status))
```

и в командах, в отправке сообщения от бота добавила параметр `message.chat.id`:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!")
```

спасибо за помощь @gil9red